# WSO2 Mediator Handler for 404 File not Found Exception

Tags: exception, proxy, wso2, http-status-code-404, wso2-esb

i'm using WSO2 4.8.1 wso2 ESB.

I developed a proxy by which i can forward a request to my tomcat Server.

I need to handle a "file not found exception" ( status code 404 ) sent me by the server and each time to make a few operations.

This is the outSequence's code of the proxy:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="addBannedUrl">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="responseStatus" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"></property>        
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('responseStatus')" regex="404">
       <then>         
           <payloadFactory media-type="json">
               <format>         {         "codice":"403",         "message":"FORBIDDEN."         }      </format>
           </payloadFactory>   
           <class name="it.innovapuglia.diogene.integration.wso2.esb.GovernanceClient"></class>
       </then>
  </filter>
</sequence>
```

I'm pretty sure the WSB enter inside the Filter Mediator each time the code returned by the tomcat server is 404, but when it enters the payloadFactory it rises an error:

```
[2015-01-19 18:05:29,787] ERROR - FilterMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,956]
Message: Il tipo di elemento "HR" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "</HR>".
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPEnvelope(TransportUtils.java:161)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:160)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,956]
Message: Il tipo di elemento "HR" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "</HR>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 29 more
```

What's wrong with the code?

Is it because the error response message of the tomcat server is something like this?

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - Not Found</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Not Found</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52</h3></body></html>
```

...has the esb xml parser some difficulties to parse it?
How can i avoid this exception?
thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to understand the error what it mentioned by this line;

```
Message: Il tipo di elemento "HR" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "</HR>".
    at c
```

BTW Your outsequence logic is right? I think you need to place the class meditator within `<then>` tags or `<else>` tags.

Edit: Can you add text/html message builder in the axis2.xml and check.

Comment: Yes you re right, i made a mistake copying the original proxy's code. Indeed the class mediator is inside <then>(i ve corrected the first post now, thnx). BTW the error still keeps to appear. So is the syntax error the not closed hr tag in the standard error message sent by the tomcat when it catch a "file not found exception"? - i don t see any </hr>. Is there a way to make esb to ignore this message and not to parse it? I just need to build a new custom message to send to the class mediator in case of 404 error.

Comment: Here error says //ERROR - FilterMediator Error while building message//. Can you put a log mediator, before the payload factory mediator and see that log is printing or not?

Comment: First Try:
I added a log mediator custom printing the response code before the payload factory ---> it works. _____ Second Try: i added a log mediator befor payload factory setting the full level ( <log level="full" />) --->it gives me the same error about the XMLStreamException. It seams the exception rises every time the esb tries to parse the response's xml stream.As i read here in HTML,the <hr> tag has no end tag. while in XHTML,The<hr>tag must be properly closed, like this: <hr /> in my job experience i noticed this type of exception many times in the esb log Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: OK so the error in the response format. Can you keep a tcpmon between ESB and your backend (tomcat server) and check what tomcat returns?

Comment: using firebug and catching the response from the server i get the same html code i wrote before. That's because tomcat encapsulates its own response in its format (simply is the tomcat error page).

Comment: updated my answer. Check the tomcats conetnt-type of its response. Add the specific message builder in the axis2.xml fro that content-type

Comment: Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8 ... in the axis2.xml i see  <!--messageFormatter contentType="text/html"                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter" -->... i don't see the commented <!--messageBuilder contentType="X/X"
                        class="class"/--> for text/html ... have to add it? what class should have i to use? and what about message formatter? should have i to uncomment it too?

Comment: Uncomment the commented blocks. You do not need formatter. Only builder needed. Use the default class implementation listed for other content types.